# Apache Tomcat Server shutdown yet webapplication is still running

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, firefox, tomcat, windows-xp

I am using Apache Tomcat 6.0.18, I am running on Windows XP

I have a web application which I place it's war file under webapps folder. The web application runs fine, its just when I run the **shutdown.bat** the application still runs (as in I refresh the page and it doesn't come up not found).

I check the **localhost:/8080** and webpage cannot be found comes up

but when I run **localhost:/8080/myapp** my application comes up. 
I have tried this in both IE and Firefox

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is there a tomcat's shutdown message in it's logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this similar problem, This can only happen if Apache Tomcat is not configured properly. Best way is to check **build path** and look for exact directory of Apache.

Example
i.e  `C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.27`

Also look for windows service for start, restart or stop

```
Run - services.msc
```

You may want to check [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2495-services-start-disable.html) link

i.e

[image]

Comment: Hey I found out I had an instance of Tomcat that would start it self when I booted my computer up. (very strange I didn't remember creating that at all actually...) but! I killed that instance taking up that port and tomcat works fine.. (I had another issue that my JRE_HOME was set to an older version then my JDK_HOME but that's another story..) Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that tomcat is actually down (simplest way is via task manager)
The issue sounds like a caching issue. Try deleting your cache.